# Not able to get the data in a webview in detailview of splitviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

In my ipad app i'm not able to get the data in a web view. That web view is in a detail view of splitviewcontroller. That data is coming from a link.

I'm using this code.

In split view table did select row at index path

```
post=[self.postListMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
PostDetailsViewController *postDetails=[[PostDetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PostDetailViewController_Ipad" bundle:nil];
postDetails.detailItem=post.postLink;
```

In split view detail view

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem)
{
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.

    NSLog(@"detail Item String is %@",_detailItem);

    [self configureView];



}

}



- (void)configureView
{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.


    NSString* str =_detailItem;
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSLog(@"URL is ----> %@",url);
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    //[self.view addSubview:webView];

    }
```

Comment: what detailitem  you got in setDetailItem method & url you got in the log written in configureView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create new Variable at `PostDetailsViewController` .h class:-

> @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *strGetPostDetail;

and synthesize `PostDetailsViewController` .m

@synthesize strGetPostDetail

Now you can call `splitViewTable` `Delegate` `DidSelect` method:-

```
post=[self.postListMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
PostDetailsViewController *postDetails=[[PostDetailsViewController alloc]init];
postDetails.strGetPostDetail=post;
```